# Increase validity time for otp in speakeasy node library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, strongloop, one-time-password

how shall i increase the valid time for token in speak easy library.

```
var secret =speakEasy.generateSecret({length:20});
        var token = speakEasy.totp({
          secret: secret.base32,
          encoding: 'base32',
          step:100
        });
```

by default it is valid for some seconds after that it verified is false

```
var verified=speakEasy.totp.verify({
                    secret:secret,
                    encoding:'base32',
                    token:token
                });
```

you can check below links

http://speakeasyjs.github.io/speakeasy/docs/speakeasy/2.0.0/global.html
https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation links](http://speakeasyjs.github.io/speakeasy/docs/speakeasy/2.0.0/global.html#totp) you provided, `step` is the attribute which with `time` and `epoch` is used to invalidate the token after some time.

```
var secret = speakEasy.generateSecret({length:20});
var token = speakEasy.totp({
  secret : secret.base32,
  encoding : 'base32',
  // time : Date.new(),  default is current time.
  // epoch : 0,  default is 0. It is the offset from UNIX epoch.
  // step is used, with time as time + step, to invalidate the token.
  step : 100
});
```

[image]

So, if `epoch` and `time` are set to defaults, `step` can be used to define the time of token's validity in seconds. You used `step : 100`. That is why, your token was invalidating after 100 seconds. So, if you increase the time of `step`, the token's validity can be increased.

**Note: The times are in seconds.**

Hope this helps. or for queries comment.

Comment: it does not lasts for 100 seconds.it gets invalidated before 100 seconds; i think 10 to 20 seconds